# Disable changing email in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase allows users to change their email client side with

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.updateEmail("example@example.com")
```

However, I would like to disable this feature entirely - obviously, I offer no way to access it on my app by default, but if an attacker managed to trick the user into install a Chrome extension or otherwise was able to access client credentials, I would always want it to fail if possible.

Is there anywhere on the Firebase auth console where I can change this functionality or a Cloud function that would stop users from changing their email?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment in time, I do not see anything in the console or otherwise to disable this functionality. As it stands, there are only two Cloud Functions available for Firebase Auth events - user [creation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) and [deletion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion), so that would probably not be applicable to this use case either. The only thing I can think of is to just use the Admin SDK and your own API / backend to facilitate [custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) for this scenario.